# Dynamic code syntax error reporting

Tags: c++, c++17

Full code is below. Any feedback is welcomed.

I am trying to implement `syntax error reporting` like `GCC` and other `interpreters/compilers`. I am sure this can be improved and hence why I was pointed to this part of **Stackexchange** from **SO**.

**Full program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string_view>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <stack>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string code = "(* n (fac (- n 1))";

    int line = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int length = code.length();
    bool balanced;
    std::stack<char> parantheses_stack;

    for(const char c: code){
        if(c == '\n'){
            ++line;
            column = 0;
        } else {
            ++column;
        }

        if(c == ')' && parantheses_stack.empty())
            balanced = false;
        else if(c == '('){
            parantheses_stack.push(c);
            continue;
        }
        else if(!parantheses_stack.empty() && c == ')'){
            if(parantheses_stack.top() == '('){
                parantheses_stack.pop();
            }
            else if(parantheses_stack.top() != '('){
                balanced = false;
            }
        }
    }

    balanced = (!parantheses_stack.empty()) ? false : true;
    if(!balanced){
        printf("Data:\nline: %d\ncolumn: %d\nposition: %d\nlength: %d\n\n", line, column, position, length);
        printf("Syntax error:%d, %d parathesis out of balance, expected a ')'\n", line, column + 1);
        std::cout << code + "\n";
        std::cout << std::setw(column + 2) << "^\n"; 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## You don't handle the case of too many closing parentheses

If there are too many closing parentheses, you set `balanced = false` inside the `for`-loop, but then continue processing characters. And the value of `balanced` is overwritten immediately after the end of the loop. Furthermore, you don't even have an error message for this case.

## You don't need a stack

If you just want to match parentheses, and not squared/curly/angle brackets, you don't need to maintain a stack. Instead, just keep a counter for how many unmatched open brackets you have seen so far:

```
int balance = 0;

for (const char c: code) {
    // Count lines and columns
    if (c == '\n'){
        ++line;
        column = 0;
        continue;
    } else {
        ++column;
    }

    // Handle opening parentheses
    if (c == '(') {
        ++balance;
        continue;
    }

    // Handle closing parentheses
    if (c == ')') {
        if (--balance < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After this loop, `balance` should be zero. If it's negative, you know there was a closing parenthesis too many, if it's positive, there were too few.

## Don't use `system()`

`system()` is a very expensive function call, since it starts a new shell process, which in turn needs to parse and handle the command `"pause"`. Apart from being inefficient (although that doesn't matter much in this case), it is also not portable, as this will only work on Windows.

A better way is to use C++ code to wait for any character:

```
std::cin.get();
```

Although even better would be to not pause at all. If you start your program from `cmd.exe`, the window should not disappear. If you run it from a code editor or IDE, then check if that has an option to pause before closing the window.

## Don't mix `printf()` and `std::cout`

Be consistent and use one way to print text. Since this is C++ code, stick with the C++ way to print text. If you really want to use format strings, then you'll need C++20 to get [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), or C++23 to get the best of both worlds with [`std::print()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print), or use the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) to get that same functionality also in older versions of C++.

## Add a test suite

Make the code that checks the balance of parentheses a function that takes a string as an argument. Then you can call it multiple times. You can then make a test suite that runs it for different input strings that check different corner cases.

Comment: I'd suggest an even more general function which would accept opening and closing characters to check for `{}` or `[]`, etc.

Comment: Hi G. Sliepen, what about error syntax reporting? I use Fmt too.